# Graph Class: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, typeerror, python-class

```
class _Edges(defaultdict):

    def __missing__(self, vertex):
        self.setdefault(vertex, True)

    def __delitem__(self, dst):
        self[dst] = False

    def del_vertex(self, dst):
        super().__delitem__(dst)

class Graph(defaultdict):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(_Edges)
    
    def copy(self):
        return super().__copy__()
```

I'm trying to write a class that makes a graph but when I try to call the copy function I get the error. Should I write my own `__copy__`? I thought that I could use `defaultdict`'s copy to copy the graph.

The copy class is supposed to create an exact copy of the graph by calling `graph.copy()`
ex.

```
g = Graph() 
g['a']['b'] = 5
x = g.copy()
```

This would make an exact copy but i get the error stated above instead

Comment: For starters, your `__missing__` implementation is wrong... it always returns `None` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it might be better ?? to call `super().copy()` rather than call the magic method directly.

Comment: I made that so if i tried to make an unweighted edge it would come out with a value of true. Just to indicate that the edge exists but it doesn't have weight,

Comment: I tried the super.copy() and i got the same error                                                                      
    return super().copy()
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: You need to look at where `Graph` is instantiated; is it created with 1 argument as you've defined it to expect? 2? Or 3 as the error is telling you?

Answer (score 1):

Based on testing, I'm fairly sure that the `__copy__` implementation of `defaultdict` will call `__init__` on `Graph` with at least two arguments:

- the [`default_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory); and
- the object that is being copied.

To address that, you could modify your `Graph` class to be:

```python
class Graph(defaultdict):
  def __init__(self, *args):
    if len(args) == 0:
      super().__init__(_Edges)
    else:
      super().__init__(*args)
```

so if it is being called as part of a copying operation (when `args` contains a value), all the values are simply passed along to the `defaultdict` implementation; but if `args` is empty, the `defaultdict` implementation is called with only the `default_factory` argument. With this implementation, you may not need to provide a `copy` or `__copy__`, as defaulting to the one provided by `defaultdict` is sufficient.